# Не складываются десятичные числа jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу разобраться, почему складываются/минусуются только целые числа

Есть небольшой калькулятор со скрытым инпутом, в котором есть значение value, при нажатии "+", "-" должно происходить сложение/вычитание в том числи и десятичных числе. Сейчас складываются только целые числа

https://jsfiddle.net/L08danx8/

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="form-kitchen">
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='modal-kitchen__calc'>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='price' value='139.90'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='calc__value'>
                <span class="value__text">Количество: </span>
                <input type='text' onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d\.]+/g,'')" name='col' value='0' />
                <a class='minus'>-</a>
                <a class='plus'>+</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="modal-kitchen__sum">руб.</td>
    </table>
  <input type="submit" class="form-kitchen__btn" value="Заказать">
</form>
```

JS

```
    var order={};
$('.minus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1.0;
    count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
    return false;
});
$('.plus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1.0);
    $input.change();
    return false;
});
$('.modal-kitchen__calc').on('change','.calc__value input',calculate_price);
function calculate_price() {
    var $input=$(this),
        count=$input.val(),
        price=parseFloat($input.parents('td').prev().children('input').val()),
        sum=parseInt(price*count),
        item=$input.parents('tr').children('tr').eq(2);
    $input.parents('td').next().text((print_price(sum))).data('sum',sum);
    if (count===0) {
        delete(order[num]);
        calc_sum();
        return;
    }
    order[item]={sum: sum,count: count};
    calc_sum();
}
function calc_sum() {
    var sum=0;
    for (var key in order) {
        sum+=order[key].sum;
    }
    $('.modal-kitchen__calc').find('td').last().text(print_price(sum));
}
function print_price(v) {
    return ((v*100)+'').replace(/(..)$/,',$1 руб.')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите `parseInt` из строки

`sum=parseInt(price*count),`

оба множителя - `price` и `count` - уже и так являются числами, их произведение, естественно, тоже - число.

*Update*

```
function print_price(v) {
   var a = v.toFixed(2);
   return a + " руб.";
}
```

*Update 2*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".calc__value").find('input').change();
  // или
  $(".calc__value input").change();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но теперь каждая третья итерация не округляет. Прим. 41970.000000000,01

Comment: @atomr Какие итерации? О чем речь?

Comment: В последнем вашем апдейте вопрос решился, спасибо большое еще раз

Comment: @atomr Не за что. Успехов в программировании!

Comment: Здравствуйте еще раз. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не понимаю как решить. Если в инпуте количества value уже стоит "1" по дефолту, то почему не передается при загрузке страницы цена одного товара? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, если не трудно https://jsfiddle.net/atomr/L08danx8/2/

Comment: @atomr см. *Update 2* в ответе.

Comment: Благодарю безмерно еще раз :) Оказалось все намного проще, чем я пытался сделать